# Button for my next page table cannot generate table ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, datatables

I'm newbie in programming I have a table that has an activation button, on the first page of the table all of the buttons are functioning well, but when it proceed to the next page of the table only the activation button is not working. It can't generate table ID. Anyone who encountered the same issue please help me.

Here is my HTML Codes:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($merchants as $e)
        <tr>
            <td><img src={{$e->logo}} width="50px" height="50px" /></td>
            <td>{{ $e->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $e->getMerchantCategory->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $e->owner }}</td>
            <td>{{ $e->markup_pct }}</td>
            <td>{{ $e->address }}</td>
            <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($e->opening)->format('h:i A') }}</td>
            <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($e->closing)->format('h:i A') }}</td>
            <td>{{ $e->isAvailable() ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
            <td>
                @if (!is_null($e->status_id))
                    <span
                        class="{{ $e->getStatus->class }}">{{ $e->getStatus->name }}</span>
                @else

                @endif
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ url('merchants/' . $e->id . '') }}"
                    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Info"
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a>
                <a href="{{ url('merchants/' . $e->id . '/edit') }}"
                    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"
                    class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                @if ($e->status_id == 1)
                    <a data-id="{{ $e->id }}" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        title="Deactivate"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn_status_change"><i
                            class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                @else
                    <a data-id="{{ $e->id }}" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        title="Activate"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn_status_change"><i
                            class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                @endif

            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

This is my JS Codes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $('#merchants').DataTable();

  $('.btn_status_change').on('click', function(e) {
    var est_id;
    est_id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(est_id);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'merchant/status-change',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          id: est_id
        }
      })
      .done(function() {
        // location.reload();
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert("ERROR!");
        // location.reload();
      });
  });
  $('.btn_dlt_confirmation').on('click', function(e) {
    var est_id;
    est_id = $(this)[0].dataset.id;
    $('#merchant_id').val(est_id);
  });

  $('.btn_confirmed_delete').on('click', function(e) {
    var id;
    id = $('#merchant_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'merchants/' + id,
        type: 'delete',
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        location.reload();
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.message);
        location.reload();
      });

  });
});
```

Comment: I made you a snippet to format your code. If your problem is jQuery HTML, then please post HTML instead of CF. If the problem is the CF, please tag it.

Comment: Why would you reload a page in an ajax success, that is the same as just submitting a form to itself

Comment: My activation button on my first table page doesn't have any problem and it reload automatically then the status will changed. But when the table exceed into the second page the activation button will not work.

Comment: Your question has some PHP code, so please tag PHP as well